# Average quarters of a matrix

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda

If I have a *N×N* two dimensional array , And I want to average every quarter of it to be the same number like the following:

```
matrix = [ 1 2 4 6
           6 7 1 1
           9 8 3 6
           4 7 9 2 ]
```

and after applying cuda kernel on it the result would be:

```
result = [ 4 4 3 3
           4 4 3 3
           7 7 5 5
           7 7 5 5 ]
```

How could this be implemented with C cuda kernels ?

Comment: What is the problem size you are interested in?

Comment: Are you doing this operation on one very large matrix, or many smaller matricies?

Comment: Problem size is about one matrix with dimensions [4000×4000].

Comment: Questions are more usually of the form, "I have X problem, can you help me with it?". Your question seems to fit the form, "I have X problem, can you solve it for me?" What have you tried? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why do you want to use CUDA for this, instead of the CPU?

Comment: @SamehKamal... do you want every 4 elements to be averaged, or every quarter of the matrix?

Comment: @sgar91.. every quarter of the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular problem in doing this sort of operation. The approach that immediately springs to mind would be something like:

1. Label each submatrix you wish to average
2. Perform a prefix sum on each labelled region and transform the resulting sums into means
3. Fill each labelled region with the corresponding mean value.

The thrust template library which ships with the CUDA toolkit contains most of the algorithms you will need to implement this. The only user code required will be a functor to label each submatrix, which should be pretty trivial to write.

Comment: The real problem I am facing is averaging filter of pixel and this filter has a dynamic size, that I average the pixel value with all its neighbors within the specified size of the filter

Comment: @SamehKamal: So if that is the "real problem", then why did you waste everyone's time by asking what is effectively a completely different question?

Comment: Solving this simple question will lead me to the solution of the real problem, That I just needed some help with averaging sub matrices(two-dimensional arrays), And that what I've asked

Comment: @sameh kamal: if you have a dynamic filter size or are intending to filter the same image multiple times with different filters, then the canonical solution would be using a summed area table. Also note that from a CUDA point if view, summing quarters of a 4000x4000 matrix and summing many 4x4 submatrices of a 4000x4000 matrix are very different programming problems